# Is it possible to upgrade a Windows XP machine to Windows 7 without having to reinstall?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

I have a client who wants to upgrade his Windows XP machine to Windows 7. He a lot of important software that he wishes to keep. Instead of doing a clean install of windows 7 and manually installing each and every program, could I do an upgrade of windows 7 without losing and installed programs or files? is this even possible? what would be the best route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot, as the technicality in how the OS works is changed too much. You can, however, go from [Windows XP to Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-vista) (if you have the license), then to Windows 7, without losing your data. This [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) page explains all the upgrade paths available to Windows 7.